# Woocommerce show custom button in specific category

Tags: php, woocommerce

It's possible to show this code only on a specific category ?

thank you!

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','cmk_additional_button');
function cmk_additional_button() {
    echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt">Change me please</button>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cmk_additional_button' );
function cmk_additional_button() {
    global $product;

    if (
        count(
            array_intersect(
                allowed_categories(), // Allowed Categories.
                wc_get_product_cat_ids( $product->get_id() ) // Product category ids.
            ) // Check any match for allowed category.
        ) > 0 // Pass the condition if atleast one allowed category exists.
    ) {
        echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt">Change me please</button>';
    }
}

function allowed_categories() {
    return array( 18, 20 );
}
```

1. The function `cmk_additional_button` do a conditional check whether the current product have allowed categories id.
2. If it have then displays the button.
3. Function `allowed_categories` is return an array of allowed category which is used to compare with the current single product's categories.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue was resolved.